# How Do I Send a Response to a POST Request with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, post

I am trying to implement a simple webpage that uses AJAX to update some text when I press a button. I am using HTML for the page, Javascript for the client side, and Python for the server side. I am using pure CGI for educational purposes.

I am able to get the POST request all the way through my Python script correctly, but I can't find what I should do after that in order to return a value to tthe ResponseText field.

**The Code**

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      test
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="buttonClicked()">
      click me
    </button>
    <script>

      function buttonClicked() {
          document.getElementById("modify").innerHTML = post('clicked=true', 'input.py')
      }

      function post(data, dest) {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                  return xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("POST", dest, true);
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
          xmlhttp.send(data);
      }   

    </script>
    <p id="modify">
      this is the text to be modified by the button
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

input.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
input = cgi.FieldStorage()

with open('/var/www/test/output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(input.getvalue("clicked") + "\n")

clicked = input.getvalue("clicked") == "true"

with open('/var/www/test/output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write("clicked: " + str(clicked))
```

output.txt:

```
true
clicked: True
```

The initial webpage looks as expected. After clicking the button, the text is modified to say `undefined`, which makes sense because I haven't sent anything back.

**How do I send a response to POST with Python?**

Edit:

I tried `print`, `print()`, and `sys.stdout.write()`; none did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequest` object will be returned to your callback function with the data from `input.py`'s standard output. The reason that your attempts at writing to stdout don't seem to work is because your http headers are not in the proper syntax. `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` is the text held after the headers.

The headers should look something like:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Status: 200 OK\n")
sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: text/plain\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("This is the text that will be in responseText")
```

It is also worth noting that the http request to the input.py is (I believe) in standard input. FieldStorage is just a nice way to parse through it (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1fe0fd9feb6a4472a9a1b186502eb9c0b2366326/Lib/cgi.py)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use CGI. It's an incredibly outdated way of communicating with browsers (at least 15 years).

If anything try [using Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/). Here's a very simple example to get you started on how to handle a POST request to `/login`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    return 'Login response!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here you see a complete example web app. There is a POST route that returns a simple string as the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You'll notice a) this isn't production code b) "I am using pure CGI for educational purposes."

Comment: Your sentiment about CGI is absolutely correct, though.